# Run time of brute-force string guessing bourne-shell script

Tags: for-loop, sh

I am writing a script to try to guess a string. The string is 12 characters in length and can be one of 18 different alphanumeric characters. I can confirm whether I have the correct string only once I have an entire possible solution. So I have done 12 nested for loops and in the final loop, check my answer and move on if incorrect or exit if correct. It looks like this:

```sh
for char1 in A B C ... 7 8 9
do
    for char2 in A B C ... 7 8 9
    do
        .
        .
        .
        for char12 in A B C ... 7 8 9
        do
            if [ "${char1}${char2}..." = "HELLOWORLD33" ]
            then
                echo "okay"
                exit 0
            fi
        done
    done
done
```

My questions are: 
(1) am I getting all possible combinations using this method? 
(2) as I am running this through a Bourne Shell with an old 64-bit processor (not sure of the speed), roughly how long can I expect this to take?

Thanks!

Comment: `18^12` is about a quadrillion. It's going to take a while.

Comment: Are we talking days, weeks...? I have had it running for about 10 hours now (unfortunately forgot to include something that keeps me posted on where it's up to).

Comment: It takes Python about 2.6 seconds to run through all possible 6-letter words with your 18 character dictionary, so if you multiply that by `18^6`, you get about 3 years with Python.

Comment: On my computer with your bash script, it takes 3.678 seconds to try 18^4 possibilities. Extrapolating to 18^12 possibilities, it would take about 1284.4 years.

Comment: Yikes! I'll be pulling the plug on this one :). Thanks everyone!